# Changing immutable type class attributes by way of an inherited static method

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm new to Python and indeed OOP. I have a derived class that has inherited several class attributes from the base class, some of which are mutable types, while others are immutable. The derived class has also inherited a static method that resets the class attributes to their original values.

This works fine within the base class, and it's not an issue within the derived class where the mutable type class attributes are concerned. The problem arises with the immutables. I understand I may have to completely redesign this anyway, but it does present a question about inheritance for which I can't find a satisfactory answer.

Here's a simplified illustration of the issues described above:

```
class Parent(object):
    boolean_attribute = True
    list_attribute = ['1', '2', '3']


    @staticmethod
    def static_reset():
        Parent.boolean_attribute = True
        Parent.list_attribute = ['1', '2', '3']



class Child(Parent):
    pass

print(Parent.list_attribute)
Parent.list_attribute.remove('1')
print(Parent.list_attribute)
Parent.static_reset()
print(Parent.list_attribute)

print(Parent.boolean_attribute)
Parent.boolean_attribute = False
print(Parent.boolean_attribute)
Parent.static_reset()
print(Parent.boolean_attribute)

print(Child.list_attribute)
Child.list_attribute.remove('1')
print(Child.list_attribute)
Child.static_reset()
print(Child.list_attribute)

print(Child.boolean_attribute)
Child.boolean_attribute = False
print(Child.boolean_attribute)
Child.static_reset()
print(Child.boolean_attribute)
```

The output from the above is as follows:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
True
False
True
['1', '2', '3']
['2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
True
False
False
```

Note that the static_reset method hasn't worked in the last case.

Any insights into what's going on here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would it make more sense to have a `@classmethod` to update class attributes?

Comment: There are various issues that combine to create the behavior you're seeing.  If you're new to Python and new to OO, I'd suggest you start by googling for other questions about class attributes, mutable and immutable objects, etc., and try some simpler examples before attempting to mix all these things together in one.  An answer to this question would have to explain basically everything about how attributes and mutation work in Python, which is information you can probably find elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *getting* an attribute, and that attribute isn't present, the whole class hierarchy is consulted. This is how inheritance works in Python.

But when *setting* an attribute, it is done directly on the object (instance or class). This is how overriding works.

You have set the `Child.boolean_attribute` attribute, where it didn't exist before. This is different from *mutating* the list referenced by `list_attribute`; you never *set* that attribute. `Child.list_attribute` only ever *gets* the attribute, after which you use the `list.remove()` method on the list object (not `Child` or `Parent`) to alter the contents.

You'd see the same behaviour if you actually set `list_attribute`:

```
Child.list_attribute = ['foo', 'bar']
```

You can see this happen when you use the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...     boolean_attribute = True
...     list_attribute = ['1', '2', '3']
... 
>>> class Child(Parent):
...     pass
... 
>>> vars(Child)
dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(Parent)
dict_proxy({'boolean_attribute': True, '__module__': '__main__', 'list_attribute': ['1', '2', '3'], '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> Child.boolean_attribute = False
>>> vars(Child)
dict_proxy({'boolean_attribute': False, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
```

Note how `Child` now has a `boolean_attribute` entry too.